# Must each API call have a unique AddAntiForgery token?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

I know that using calling Html.AddAntiForgeryToken within a FORM will work.
But for cases where there is no Form, where/how should the antiforgery token be obtained?

And must each token be unique? Or can a web app use the same antiforgery token throughout its entire session?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with `AntiForgeryToken`?

Comment: Im wondering if the same valid token can be used for all of my http requests within the user's session (so long as the session is still valid).

Answer (score 0):

AntiForgeryToken value belongs rather to page then to `form`. If you place several forms (not nested!!! of course) on the same page with `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` then all values will be the same. When the page is reloaded (after `GET` or `POST`) then the value changes.
Internally, Web Server set `HttpOnly` Cookie (the name defined in `AntiForgeryConfig` class) and compare the value received with that cookie value.
What if you make an API (AJAX) call from that page? Certainly you can make as many calls as you wish.
What if there is no `form` on the page? You need to add a *fake* `form`. Something like this.

```
@{
    var attr = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    attr.Add("id", "anti-forgery"); //sic!
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "fake-form", FormMethod.Post, attr))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
```

And then set up **all** your AJAX calls at once.

```
<script>
    'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            headers: antiForgery({}) //put antiforgerytoken into ajax request header
        });
        function antiForgery(data) {
            data.__RequestVerificationToken = $('#anti-forgery input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
            return data;
        }

    });

</script>
```

On the server side you need to consume and validate the request. Following approach uses custom attribute class.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class ValidateJsonAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
        AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
    }
}
```

And now you only decorate your controller methods with this attribute.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateJsonAntiForgeryToken] //this one
public async Task<JsonResult> ProcessRq(MyModel model)
{
    //do work
}
```

If you create a pure API (RESTfull) service then there is similar approach. A client app first have to request and receive some kind of authentication token and add it to all next requests (during the session).

Comment: I guess the big question is: Can the antiforgery token be generated outside of a Form?

Comment: In this case it is called `API Key`